# jQuery 'this' in callback

Tags: filepicker.io

I have the filepicker.io dialog coming up fine but on the success call back I seem to lose my 'this' context.

So my code is like this

```
var fileProcess ={

 saveFileInfo: function () {
.....process info here
},

selectFile: function () {
        filepicker.pick({ mimetype: 'image/*' }, function (Blob) {
           this.saveFileInfo();
        });

    }

}
```

So is there something like "context: this" like I can do in an ajax call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating a new variable named `self` or `me` set to the current value of `this` OUTSIDE your callback. Then, you use closures, so you can access `this` from your callback through `me` or `self`.

Like:

```
this.mesg = "Hello";
var self = this;
function handler() {
  alert(self.mesg);
}
```

later after a context switch...

```
handler(); // Will alert 'Hello'
```

EDIT: Oh nuts... Just realized that won't work... Try:

```
function handler() {
  alert(this.msg);
}
var newHandler = handler.bind(this);
```

Later...

```
newHandler();
```

`Function.prototype.bind()` takes an object, and returns a function. Whenever the returned function is called, the object passed to `bind()` is used as `this`.